# Large Grease Pencil File Lagging in Blender 2.92

Tags: grease-pencil, performance

I have been using Blender 2.92 for a few months (using the grease pencil) and it started lagging a lot on a specific file (0.92GB), particularly on specific scenes.  It lags so much that I can’t sculpt, undo, select, switch modes etc. without waiting at least 30 seconds. I really can’t continue my project at all.

I have tried to open my file on a computer that has lots of RAM, but the problem persists.

I also tried un-checking *Global Undo* in my settings, reducing the lag a bit, but it still does not work well enough.

I saw on YouTube that in earlier versions of Blender, we could modify the *Window Draw Method,* but I can’t figure out where to find it in my preferences (and don’t know if this solution would work).

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention I was using the Grease Pencil :)

Comment: You can click the [edit] button to modify your question ;)

Comment: thanks @HISEROD!